# How to find indices all elements in Int64 list whose value is greater than specific value?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using VS2013 with .NET framework 4.5

I have a list of Int64--> 
1. I have to calculate difference bwtween two successive elements.
2. If this difference is higher than certain thresold then I have to get index of that element.
Step 1 is done ,step 2 I am stuck

Request your help.Thanks in advance

Comment: You might like the Zip method.

Comment: Hi Welcome to stackoverflow, It is good you tried something, can you show us your code for step 1 and your attempts for step two. what issues you faced while attempting step2

Comment: For Step 1 , I used extension method pairwaise . var BCM_ARC_Diff = FVSyncFrame_BCM_FD.Pairwise((x, y) => y - x);

Comment: Pairwise isn't a standard .NET extension method. Is this your own method?

Comment: Yes ,It is non-standard method , I came across on another Stack Overflow post

Comment: Please ready [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question. It is really hard to help you with your question and your comments

Comment: Example of Intended behaviour : List of Int64 (5,67,78,100)--->Diffrenece between successive elements (62,11,22),Chosen thresold is 15 ,So I should get Index of Elements 62 and 22 ie 0 an 2 .That wat I can confirm in original list at Index 1 and 3 jumps of value more than 15 occured

Comment: You should update your question with your code, not post it in comments. It will be easier to read that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the folowing.

```
var list = new List<long>{5,67,78,100};
var threhold = 15;
var result = list.Select((x,index)=>new {Index=index,Value=x})
                 .Zip(list.Skip(1),(x,y)=>new {Index=x.Index,Value = Math.Abs(x.Value-y)})
                 .Where(x=>x.Value>threhold)
                 .Select(x=>x.Index);
```

**Output**

```
0 
2
```

Comment: Man , You are genius